# Inserting each line of an excel column as a parameter in a httpGET api-request-method. I need a json-file for each line of that excel column

Tags: python, excel, pandas, api, python-requests

I have an excel file called table.xlsx. I tried to write a python script which reads every value of each line of a specific column called 'ABC'. In that column 4667 lines are written. Each line has to be inserted as a parameter in a GET method string (http protocol) in order to get 4667 json-files with all the necessary data from the REST-Api-Server. I tried the following python script:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd 

get_all_ABC = pd.read_excel('C:\Users\XXX\XXX2\XXX3\table.xlsx', skiprows=1).set_index('ABC')

r = requests.get('http://localhost:5000/api/sensors/data?ABC={get_all_ABC}')
print (r.json())
```

Reading each line of the column 'ABC' of the excel file does work by itself and the `requests.get` code also works by itself if I type a certain specific string of the column 'ABC' in the http-GET-string. When I run the code in the command window (cmd) with all the dependencies I get a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`, but I do not get why. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to fetch all 4667 JSON files in a single request by requesting all of the ABC values at once? Does the API support that, and what syntax does it expect? (Even if it does, you might have to break this into a few requests still in case you run up against a request URL length limit)

Comment: But it might be simplest to just loop over the separate values in get_all_ABC and make 4667 separate requests.

Comment: @Rup : This could be it. I can ask the person who set up the API for us. Maybe it does not allow so much requests at the same time.

Comment: @Rup: mhh, ok that is not the problem. I reduced the excel file to just 5 lines in the column 'ABC' and it still does not work. But, maybe only one API-request at a time is allowed. I try to loop over the values. I still do not know, how to do it (I am a programming rookie), but I guess a for-loop.

Comment: Actually I think your string construction is wrong too: you need a leading `f` to do string interpolation, i.e. `f'http://localhost:5000/api/sensors/data?ABC={get_all_ABC}'` (assuming you're using Python 3.6+). However you're still writing the ABC list as Python array i.e. `[1,2,3]` which likely is not the syntax that the API supports if it does support multiple IDs in the one request. But yes you'll have to ask whoever wrote the API to know what it supports.

Comment: You can use `.apply()` and make one call per line

Comment: thanks I will try that. However, the RestAPI Server does not respond at the moment and the person who programmed the API endpoints is not in the office at the moment. He will be back on monday. I will report back:).

Comment: @Let'stry Could you give a hint how to program it with .apply()? I do not get an approach in my head. I can get all the numbers of the column 'ABC' as a list if I use `get_all_ABC = pd.read_excel('C:\Users\XXX\XXX2\XXX3\table.xlsx', skiprows=1, usecols="A").set_index('ABC')`

Comment: we have to insert each string of the column 'ABC' successively as parameters in the GET-method.

Comment: something like `get_all_ABC.apply(lambda x: requests.get('http://localhost:5000/api/sensors/data?ABC='+x["link"]),axis = 1)`

Comment: @Let'stry thanks I will try it out.